# Problem with dates in Postgresql and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, named-scope

I want to do the following:  Find all articles with where `Time.now` is between `article.due_date` and `article.due_date - 8.hours`. I'm having a lot of trouble trying to get it right.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What is it that you are having problems with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who said that algebra was worthless?

The two conditions you stated in your question.

```
T <= DUE
T >= DUE - 8h
```

Are the same as these two conditions.

```
DUE >= T
DUE <= T + 8h
```

You can apply now apply this to a query and/or scope without having to do datetime gymnastics in your database.

```
named_scope :near_due, lambda {{ :conditions => ["due_date >= ? AND due_date <= ?", Time.now, Time.now + 8.hours] }}
```

Comment: Ha. I just solved this myself.  Had to relookup the rules for inequalities. Probably don't need the lambda unless we're passing the hours, which may indeed be a good idea. Have an accepted answer for your work though :)

Comment: You definitely need the lambda, otherwise `Time.now` will only be evaluated the first time your model is cached.